# Kendo ui Grid displaying the Grouping Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo UI Grid with Asp.net MVC web api.

I have a web api controller which receives datasource request object

```
Public DataSourceResult GetCustomers(DataSourceRequest request) {

return customerService.GetCustomers().ToDataSourceResult(request);

}
```

which returns the data to the client side.

I have Angular controller for listing the customers which uses Kendo ui web grid.

I want to implement *server side pagination sorting filtering and nice feature called grouping*.

The pagination works fine. The result returned contains the data object and the count of the total number of records which is very fine for normal use...

The datasource of the grid has the transport property which takes in the url rather than using the read property of  transport objects.

I am calling my angular service which takes in the parameters and fires the query to the web api controller when returned it the success function is passed with the data from the request.

All this works fine with normal pagination.

I have not hardcoded any column names but the schema of the data source is

```
schema :{data:"data",count:"count"}
```

which also works fine but I am implementing the server side grouping which requires passing in of the column name

the data returned from the server when grouping applied on the web api controller is totally different in schema than what is returned when grouping is not applied

which causes the data like aggregates and items being displayed as the column name.

What should be done to display the grouped data into the grid am I missing something?